# Unable to scrape quote of the day from forbes

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to use python + Beautiful Soup to scrape the quote of the day from the forbes website.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request

url = requests.get('http://www.forbes.com/quotes/1/')
url = url.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(url,'html.parser')
print(soup.find('p',{'class' : 'ng-binding'}))
```

When I run this code, I get output : None

Answer (score 2):

The quote itself is *loaded dynamically* from a different resource URL. Make request to it instead parsing the JSON response:

```
>>> import requests
>>>
>>> url = "http://www.forbes.com/forbesapi/thought/uri.json?enrich=true&query=1&relatedlimit=5"
>>> response = requests.get(url)
>>> data = response.json()
>>>
>>> data['thought']['quote'].strip()
u'Teach self-denial and make its practice pleasure, and you can create for the world a destiny more sublime that ever issued from the brain of the wildest dreamer.'
```

Comment: is there any documentation for this forbes api?

Comment: and also how do I make api call for **quote of the day** with this @alecxe ?